# Checking if sequence is almost strictly in ascending order using Java

Tags: java

This was part of my interview questions.

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, I have to determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.
>
> For instance,
>
> For `sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1]`, the output should be
>
> `almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false`
>
> There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a >strictly increasing sequence.
>
> For sequence = `[1, 3, 2]` the output should be
>
> `almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true`
>
> We can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 2]`. Alternately, we can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 3]`.
>
> The function must return true if it is possible to remove one element from the array in order to get a strictly increasing sequence, otherwise return `false`.

The conceptual algorithm that the interviewer wanted was below with **Java**:

```
boolean almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
    int seq1 = 0;
    int seq2 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++){
        if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i + 1]) seq1++;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < sequence.length - 2; k++){
        if(sequence[k] >= sequence[k + 2]) seq2++;
    }

    return !(seq1 + seq2 > 2);
}
```

but I didn't get the part comparing `sequence[i]` with `sequence[i+1]` and`sequence[i+2]` to increment the counter which are `seq1` and `seq2`. How does this cover all the cases?

Comment: Have you tested the code with some set of inputs?

Comment: No, the posted code is totally incorrect. Please have a look [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405279/q-solve-almostincreasingsequence-in-java-codefights] for the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does this cover all the cases?

It does not.

This algorithm is wrong.

Consider the input array

```
{1,2,3,5,4,6,7,9,8}
```

It is **not** an almost strictly increasing sequence, since you have to remove at least two elements (for example, 4 and 9) to make it strictly increasing.

However, the code you posted will return `true`, since `seq1 + seq2 == 2` (`seq1` is `2` and `seq2` is `0`).

A possible solution:

1. iterate over the array, comparing each pair of adjacent elements.
2. The first time you find a pair that is not strictly increasing (a[i] >= a[i+1]), you have to check if removing either a[i] or a[i+1] makes the array strictly increasing.

   - If you remove a[i], you must ensure a[i-1] < a[i+1].
   - If you remove a[i+1], you must ensure a[i] < a[i+2].
   - If this validation fails, you return `false`.
3. Otherwise you continue testing the rest of the array.

   - If you find another pair that is not strictly increasing you return false.
   - otherwise you return true.

Answer (score 1):

NO, its not cover all the cases.

If its given from the interviewer side .

They actually tested your capacity to tracking the actual fault of this code and modify if necessary. And asking the proper reason what is happening before and after modifying the code.